# Python: File doesn't read whole file, io.FileIO does - why?

Tags: python, io

The following code, executed in python 2.7.2 *on windows*, only reads in a fraction of the underlying file:

```
import os

in_file = open(os.path.join(settings.BASEPATH,'CompanyName.docx'))
incontent = in_file.read()
in_file.close()
```

while this code works just fine:

```
import io
import os

in_file = io.FileIO(os.path.join(settings.BASEPATH,'CompanyName.docx'))
incontent = in_file.read()
in_file.close()
```

Why the difference? From my reading of the docs, they should perform identically.

Comment: Could be related to encoding, could be that you're opening the file with default settings, open() defaults to just 'r', try open(filename, 'rb') to force binary mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode, or the `read()` will stop at the first EOF character it finds. And a `docx` is a ZIP file which is guaranteed to contain such a character somewhere.

Try

```
in_file = open(os.path.join(settings.BASEPATH,'CompanyName.docx'), "rb")
```

`FileIO` reads [raw bytestreams](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase) and those are "binary" by default.

Comment: Wow! Is the root cause of this something fundamental in how Windows handles files?

Comment: @Marcin it's more about the MS Word docx file format. if you just want to read a .txt, `open()` will work just fine.

Comment: +1. As the Python 2.7 docs, [7.2. *Reading and Writing Files*], say: "Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification ...[will]... corrupt binary data like that in `JPEG` or `EXE` files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a `'b'` to the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary files."

Comment: @Marcin: The same problem occurs with FTP. It has to do with the need to translate different linebreak styles between OSes and probably some other things.